# Blazor static SSR form submission not respecting base href

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

#### My Setup

I have a .NET 8 web application which consists of API endpoints and a Blazor Web App.
My blazor web app is supposed to be served in `/temp/api/blazor` path.
I have a reverse proxy which first omits the `temp` part from the path and then passes it into the .NET app.

#### What I've already done

I have an `EditForm` in login compoent which when submitted does not include the `temp` in the request path, Though I have added the `/temp/api/blazor` into the base href of the `App.razor` component.
This is App.razor:

```
<head>
   <base href="@AppPath" />
</head>
@code {
    string AppPath {get; set;}
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
        var basepath = "temp";
        AppPath = $"/{basepath}/api/blazor/";
    }
}
```

This is part of Program.cs file:

```
app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api/blazor"), blazorApp =>
{
    blazorApp.UsePathBase("/api/blazor");
    blazorApp.UseStaticFiles();
    blazorApp.UseRouting();
    blazorApp.UseAntiforgery();
    blazorApp.UseEndpoints(routeBuilder =>
    {
        routeBuilder.MapRazorComponents<App>().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
    });
});
```

And this is my login component:

```
<EditForm method="post" OnValidSubmit="HandleLogin" Model="@loginModel" FormName="login" >    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="loginModel.Email" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <InputText type="password" @bind-Value="loginModel.Password" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
</EditForm>


@code {

    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext? HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private LoginModel loginModel { get; set; } = new LoginModel();

    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState>? authenticationState { get; set; }

    private async Task HandleLogin()
    {
        // login logic ...
        await SignInManager.SignInWithClaimsAsync(user, true, claims);
    }

    public class LoginModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; } = "";
        public string Password { get; set; } = "";
    }
}
```

#### My Problem

The problem is that The form on submit sends a reques to `http://my.local.domain:6060/api/blazor/login` which is wrong, I need it to be sent to `http://my.local.domain:6060/temp/api/blazor/api/login`. (Note that there is a `temp` segment in the correct one)

I tried to add `@rendermode InteractiveServer`, this way the code inside the handler is executed but `HttpContext` is null and I can't perform the login process successfully.

I really appreciate you providing an explanation on how I can solve this problem, and elaborations on concepts you think I've made wrong in this setup.

#### More Clarity

The asp.net core app is behind a **reverse proxy**. The `temp` segment in the path is used by the reverse proxy to figure out which app it should send the request to. The reverse proxy then omits the `temp` segement from the path and forwards it to the asp.net core app.

Comment: Setting href in OnInitializedAsync() is ... just too late.

Comment: @ℍℍ thank you, I'll try the raw string alternative. However, it worked for fetching other static files (css, js).

Comment: @ℍℍ I set href directly with a raw string, did not help.

Comment: @ℍℍ, how is it too late? `OnInitializedAsync` executes before any element is rendered.